# Calculate bearing between two decimal GPS coordinates (Arduino / C++)

Tags: c++, precision, bearing

I am trying to calculate the bearing just like in this example: [Calculate bearing between two decimal GPS coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/calculate-bearing-between-two-decimal-gps-coordinates#new-answer?newreg=0410583f53304895a7995ddf18df96b8)
, but my environment is Arduino.

I got the code translated (please see below), but I am having issues with the floating points. I need a higher resolution/precision.

Using these points:

```
double r1 = 9.935483816921979;
double r2 = -84.05334153306967;
double g1 = 9.936029735119176;
double g2 = -84.0532617256946;
```

I get these results:

```
8.194077303640654 // In the js code from the example
9.229920 // from my Arduino code
```

How can I get more precision?

```
// Here is my Arduino Code
double getBearing(double lat1,double lng1,double lat2,double lng2) {
  lat1 = radians(lat1);
  lng1 = radians(lng1);
  lat2 = radians(lat2);
  lng2 = radians(lng2);

  double dLng = lng2 - lng1;
  double dPhi = log(tan(lat2 / 2.0 + PI / 4.0) / tan(lat1 / 2.0 + PI / 4.0));

  if (abs(dLng) > PI){
    if (dLng > 0.0)
     dLng = -(2.0 * PI - dLng);
  else
    dLng = (2.0 * PI + dLng);
  }

  return fmod((degrees(atan2(dLng, dPhi)) + 360.0), 360.0); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Ed Williams' [Course Between Points](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm#Crs) formula?

Comment: See also http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37686.msg278166#msg278166

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can calculate your bearing with this function.

```
float bearing(float lat,float lon,float lat2,float lon2){

    float teta1 = radians(lat);
    float teta2 = radians(lat2);
    float delta1 = radians(lat2-lat);
    float delta2 = radians(lon2-lon);

    //==================Heading Formula Calculation================//

    float y = sin(delta2) * cos(teta2);
    float x = cos(teta1)*sin(teta2) - sin(teta1)*cos(teta2)*cos(delta2);
    float brng = atan2(y,x);
    brng = degrees(brng);// radians to degrees
    brng = ( ((int)brng + 360) % 360 ); 

    Serial.print("Heading GPS: ");
    Serial.println(brng);

    return brng;


  }
```

where variables are:

- lat =  your current gps latitude.
- lon = your current gps longitude.
- lat2 =  your destiny gps latitude.
- lon2 = your destiny gps longitude.

Comment: You never use 'delta1' in the formula, is that intentional or a mistake?

Comment: delta1 is used in the distance not in the bearing .....

Comment: Your variable float delta1 is not used anywhere !!!!!

Comment: More explanation here: [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) - "Bearing".  @عبد القادر كعوان - `delta1` isn't needed for "Bearing"; see "Distance" formula on that same page; it is used there. (`const Δφ` there is `delta1` here)