# Trying to run TransitFlow/Processing and I'm getting an error

Tags: python, pandas

I just installed TransitFlow and Preprocessing after following this link :

https://github.com/transitland/transitland-processing-animation

and I run this line of code :

```
python transitflow.py --name=chicago --bbox=-87.992249,41.605175,-87.302856,42.126747 --clip_to_bbox --exclude=o-9-amtrak,o-9-amtrakcharteredvehicle
```

Everything worked fine, except in the end, I got this error :

```
success!
5 operators successfully downloaded.
0 operators failed.
Concatenating individual operator outputs.
Calculating trip segment bearings.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'bearing'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3571, in _set_item
    loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'bearing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transitflow.py", line 406, in <module>
    df['bearing'] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_bearing_between_points(row['start_lat'], row['start_lon'], row['end_lat'], row['end_lon']), axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3040, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3117, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3574, in _set_item
    self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1189, in insert
    block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim, placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2719, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2375, in __init__
    super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 130, in __init__
    f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1
```

The data come from this site : https://transit.land/feed-registry/

I looked into transitflow.py and I retrieved the line of code who's getting me this error (I think) :

```
 df['bearing'] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_bearing_between_points(row['start_lat'], row['start_lon'], row['end_lat'], row['end_lon']), axis=1)
```

So I searched the function `calc_bearing_between_points` in transitflow.py and the script tells me to go to this forum :

```
# Calculate bearing
# See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/calculate-bearing-between-two-decimal-gps-coordinates/48911
def calc_bearing_between_points(startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong):

    startLat = math.radians(startLat)
    startLong = math.radians(startLong)
    endLat = math.radians(endLat)
    endLong = math.radians(endLong)
    dLong = endLong - startLong
    dPhi = math.log(math.tan(endLat/2.0+math.pi/4.0)/math.tan(startLat/2.0+math.pi/4.0))
    if abs(dLong) > math.pi:
        if dLong > 0.0:
            dLong = -(2.0 * math.pi - dLong)
        else:
            dLong = (2.0 * math.pi + dLong)
    bearing = (math.degrees(math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0;
    return bearing
```

So I came here and I'm asking you if you could help me?